# cut html in half using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap a website and I need to cut the HTML code in half. The problem is that the HTML code is not really well organized and I can't just use `findAll`.

Here is my code to parse the HTML code :

```
resultats = requests.get(URL)
bs = BeautifulSoup(resultats.text, 'html.parser')
```

What I want to do is to divide `bs` for each `<h2>` I find :
[image]

The solution might be really simple but I can't find it...

edit : the website, [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_sondages_sur_l'%C3%A9lection_pr%C3%A9sidentielle_fran%C3%A7aise_de_2017)

Comment: don't use image. add example data as text.

Comment: some html code or link, please

Comment: The website I'm trying to scrap : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_sondages_sur_l'%C3%A9lection_pr%C3%A9sidentielle_fran%C3%A7aise_de_2017#Avril

Answer (score 0):

this scrapes the whole text without html in it:

```
import urllib2, json, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_sondages_sur_l'%C3%A9lection_pr%C3%A9sidentielle_fran%C3%A7aise_de_2017#Avril"
resultats = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = resultats.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
soup = soup.get_text() # Extracts Text from HTML

print soup
```

If you want to leave certain information out, you could add this:

```
soup = re.sub(re.compile('yourRegex', re.DOTALL), '', soup)\
       .strip()
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work fine but I need to keep the beautifulsoup format, not text format. I need to use findAll afterwards.